# Formatting a string for DateTime show

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0

For whatever reason the data I am getting from database is coming in this format: **" 830AM"**
Also notice that extra space before number **8**
I need to format it to show as **"08:30 AM"** in Silverlight XAML or Styles.
How would we do that?

Comment: Have you tried parsing it to a DateTime or DateTimeOffset? Once you get it in that form, displaying with whatever format you want is fairly straightforward.

Comment: @DevWannabe create a SQL script that changes that column to a `DateTime` column and updates the data to a proper format. All other workarounds are just patches that will bring you trouble in the future. A bad data Model / DB structure is the hell of all developers.

Comment: @DevWannaBe then use `"{Binding MyDate, StringFormat='hh:mm tt'}` in XAML, without any converters or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that the incoming format is always the same, you could use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the DateTime object -- then convert it back to a string [with the format you want](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string timeStr = " 830AM";
string format = "h:mmtt";
DateTime time = DateTime.ParseExact(timeStr.Trim(), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string timeStrFormatted = time.ToString("hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

To do this in Silverlight XAML, you could use an `IValueConverter` in the binding.  Better still, use a read-only property on the view-model, which performs the above conversion.

Comment: they are not always in that format. The new record that get created are in good format like "08:30 AM" but this one that has been created by older software and exists in the database is in this format

Comment: @DevWannaBe in that case I really think the best way would be to write a DB script to scrub that legacy data.  If that's not possible, then you could still use the above -- just use `TryParseExact` instead of `ParseExact`.